# identify: error while loading shared libraries: libgvc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, imagemagick

On our Solano build image ubuntu14-chrome64 we install imagemagick in the pre_setup hook with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev graphviz libgraphviz-dev
```

But `identify -version` fails with

```
identify: error while loading shared libraries: libgvc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What is wrong with our imagemagick package installation there?

**UPDATE 1:**

```
$ which identify
/usr/local/bin/identify

$ ldd $(which identify) | grep not
    libgvc.so.5 => not found
    libgraph.so.4 => not found
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I did `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/identify` as @N0rbert advices but the error is left the same.

```
$ which identify
/usr/bin/identify
```

`ldd $(which identify) | grep not` outputs the same as in **UPDATE 1**

```
ls -lah /usr/bin/identify
/usr/bin/identify -> /etc/alternatives/identify

ls -lah /etc/alternatives/identify
/etc/alternatives/identify -> /usr/bin/identify.im6
```

Comment: Please add output of `which identify`, `ldd $(which identify) | grep not` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert I updated the question with the information you asked

Answer (score 0):

You have self-compiled `identify` in `/usr/local/bin/`. Possibly from the time of 12.04 LTS release or similar.

You should remove it with

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/identify
```

and then you will be able to use normal one from the repository.

Comment: I did as you advised but the error remains the same. I updated the question

Comment: Then carefully navigate to all subfolders in `/usr/local` and remove/move ImageMagick stuff out the way.